# Why are double quotes not escaped in the replace-regexp command?

Tags: regular-expressions, replace

I have text like this:

```
myvariable = ABCD,
EFGH,
IJKL,
~subsection1
MNOP,
QRST,
UVWX,
YZ
```

Which I want to transform to:

```
myvariable = "ABCD,"
"EFGH,\n" \
"IJKL,\n" \
"~subsection1\n" \
"MNOP,\n" \
"QRST,\n" \
"UVWX,\n" \
"YZ"
```

To insert a `"` character at the beginning of each line I do the following:

<kbd>C-M-%</kbd> `^.*` <kbd>RET</kbd> `"\&` <kbd>RET</kbd>

But appending `\n" \` at the end of each line is trickier. I tried:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `replace-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> `$` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\\n\\" \\` <kbd>RET</kbd>

But that results in:

```
myvariable = ABCD,\n\" \
EFGH,\n" \
...
```

So you have to do it this way:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `replace-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> `$` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\\n" \\` <kbd>RET</kbd>

**Why?**

My thinking was that the `"` character had to be escaped with `\`, but that's obviously not the case. Why do I have to escape `\` but not `"`?

Comment: Maybe you're more familiar with python regexps. If that is so, you can use them: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Regexp#Use_python_regexp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can match the beginning of line with only `^` and "replace" it with `"`.

As for the backslash:
Since the backslash is the [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) in Emacs and you want to insert a literal backslash you have to escape the escape character.

The fact that you don't have to escape the double-quote here is because you are using a command (`replace-regexp`).  If you would be writing the regular expression as part of an Emacs Lisp program it would be a string and *then* you would need to escape the double-quote as well.